# Offline fallback page React server worker

Tags: reactjs, service-worker

I'm rather new to service workers. So excuse me in advance if my question is simple.
I'm trying to implement an offline page for my React application. Every one is suggesting the following code:

```js
sw.addEventListener("fetch", (event) => {
  
    event.respondWith(
      caches.match(event.request).then((cachedResponse) => {
        return (
          cachedResponse ||
          fetch(event.request)
            .then((networkResponse) => {
              return caches.open('dynamic').then((cache) => {
                cache
                  .put(event.request, networkResponse.clone())
                  .catch(() => {});
                return networkResponse;
              });
            })
            .catch(() => {
              return caches.open(STATIC_ASSETS_NAME).then((cache) => {
                return cache.match("/offline.html").then(() => {
                  return new Response("/offline.html", {
                    headers: { "Content-Type": "text/html" },
                  });
                });
              });
            })
        );
      })
    );
  
});
```

The problem is that in React, responses basically need js file which represents a component, not an html file. So this doesn't work for React and throws error.
Can anyone please help me out? thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need [`react-detect-offline`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-detect-offline) (it has also downloadable [type](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react-detect-offline) support). You can place your top level component in `<Online>` and fallback component in `<Offline>`.

Comment: thanks for you input. I just tried it, but it only works when user is using the app and goes offline, It doesn't work if you referesh when offline or enter the app when offline. That is also when everything is cached

Comment: Did you try to use [`react-native-offline`](https://www.npmjs.com/package//react-native-offline)? This lib seems to be more advanced.

Comment: If above lib won't work, i would consider to create proxy web app, which would be run before your *React* app. This app would cache `index.html` and check internet connection - if there would be no internet, it would return `index.html` in response or would redirect to your *React* app. This solution and keeping `react-detect-offline` in your codebase should cover all cases.

Comment: I haven't yet unfortunately. Although  I was hoping to understand this topic in Service Worker and how to handle this case in SPAs

Answer (score -1):

In above code, you need to ensure that the offline page includes the necessary JavaScript to bootstrap the React application. I adjusted your service worker.

```
const STATIC_ASSETS_NAME = 'static-assets';
const DYNAMIC_CACHE_NAME = 'dynamic';
const OFFLINE_URL = '/offline.html';

// Precache the offline page during the service worker installation
self.addEventListener('install', (event) => {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(STATIC_ASSETS_NAME)
      .then((cache) => cache.add(OFFLINE_URL))
  );
});

// Handle fetch events
self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request).then((cachedResponse) => {
      if (cachedResponse) {
        // Return the cached response if found
        return cachedResponse;
      }
      // Fallback to network
      return fetch(event.request).then((networkResponse) => {
        return caches.open(DYNAMIC_CACHE_NAME).then((cache) => {
          // Cache the dynamic content
          cache.put(event.request, networkResponse.clone()).catch(() => {});
          return networkResponse;
        });
      }).catch(() => {
        // Return the offline page if both cache and network fail
        return caches.match(OFFLINE_URL).then((offlineResponse) => {
          return offlineResponse || new Response('Offline page missing', {
            status: 404,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' }
          });
        });
      });
    })
  );
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I did all of that already. Still doesn't work since offline.html file is not something that the fetch requests are expecting. That's why it throws error